# What was Karl Marxs views on drug use?

Tags: communism, drugs

Considering the involvement of leftist guerrillas in south america in the drug trade got me thinking. How does that consolidate with the idea that the communist revolution is supposed to be for the betterment of the people while drugs have a documented bad effect on peoples well being.

That brings the question: What was Karl Marxs view on drug use? Is organisations like FARC operating contrary to their ideological fathers teachings in this matter?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: I have tried googling but all information I was able to find was heavily opinionated and I found it hard to differentiate the propaganda pices from the real historical accounts. By the way, downvoters, it would be helpfull if you let me know why I am being down voted. Should I ask on a different stackexchange site? Am I asking about a to contentios subject or is the question simply badly written.

Comment: He pretty famously thought it was up there with religion.

Comment: @lijat We have a useful question on our meta site titled [Why did my question get a downvote?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/618/24858).  In this case, I'd _guess_ that the downvotes are for lack of any evidence for prior research.

Comment: @sempaiscuba thanks for the explanation

Comment: Now: 1. Why tag this 'communism'? 2. Why bring in SA-politics with KM? 3. What did you research; anything come up with 'opium'? Not that I say 'Q is bad'; in fact *may become* excellent: But please refine this. Document here your research and separate your initial thought process (eg drugs=bad) from your reflected one. Your motivation is less relevant than the next steps.  What have you found, what is unexpectected, what do you not understand or want to know more about (but couldn't find)?

Comment: Whether FARC is contrary to Marx is ... subjective, judgemental and not really history.  Is there any evidence that Marx had an opinion on drugs?

Comment: At least Lenin would have never objected to using profit from drag sales in order to further interests of the Proletarian Revolution, since "We say that our morality is entirely subordinated to the interests of the proletariat’s class struggle."  (From "The tasks of the Youth Leagues", 1920.) Marx probably would not either....

Comment: Read [here](https://www.raceandcapitalism.com/next-chapter/karl-marx-is-for-the-kids) for more on Marx and opium, especially, Opium Wars. The bottom line is that Marx would not have condemned FARC either.

Comment: WRT South American guerrillas, you should perhaps be aware that coca use is a long-established practice among Andean cultures (at least), and arguably beneficial.

Comment: @MoisheKohan from the article you linked it kinda is obvious Marx sees drug abuse as a sympom of society not functioning properly, and, as such, a thing that should not be present in a healthy society. Soviet government, for example, combatted drug trade actively from its early days - for example in order of Sovnarkom of 31 July of 1918 № 7206-7212 it was called "the most repulsive kind of profiteering possible"; it also called to "punish this kind of profiteerers especially severily" - that's after the legalization of death sentence for profiteers caught red-handed.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Also, that Lenin quote is taken out of [context](https://www.marxists.org/archive/lenin/works/1920/oct/02.htm). One can argue about what exactly Lenin is talking here, but it definitely is not "communist can do whatever is needed to win, no matter how amoral it is".

Comment: Read Engel's Condition of the Working Class in England in 1848 and get back to us.

Comment: This doesn't seem directly related.  The Taliban are known to get funds from poppy growers in Afghanistan, that doesn't mean that Mohammed would have had an opinion about heroin.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov agreed. "[C]ommunist can do whatever is needed to win, no matter how amoral it is" would be more Stalin and Trotsky's attitude probably.

Answer (score 3):

Our modern attitude towards opiates is vastly different from that of 19th century.
E.g., addiction was not really a well known problem.

When Marx famously said that *religion is the opiate of the masses* he was comparing it to a *powerful painkiller* rather than an *addictive substance that destroys lives*.

More generally, while Marx was not very clear on the revolutionary methods he would support or oppose, it is unlikely that there are possible crimes against humanity he would have condemned, provided that they have been committed to further the proletarian revolution. Just read [The Communist Manifesto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Communist_Manifesto): if he wants to put us all in ["industrial armies"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulag) *after* he won, why would he abstain from something *before*?